# Wheelnav.js set titleRotateAngle per navItem

Tags: javascript, raphael, wheelnav.js

I build a menu using wheelnav.js which works fine however i cannot figure out how to set the .titleRotateAngle property per navItem.

As far as i get it this option is set globally for the wheelnav object. However when building a 'half-circle' menu this leads to unfavorable display of the navItems title as seen here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3ebp.png

What i want to achieve is for the first half (rounded down) NavItem Titles to be rotated 180° for better readability.

The code i used for this wheelnav can be found here:

https://hastebin.com/aqixagijop.xml

Since i cannot find anything helpful for this specific problem in the wheelnav.js documentation i hope someone of you might have stumbled over this problem as well and knows a fix.

Cheers and Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize wheelnav with `initWheel`. After initialization each navItem configurable individually. Without initialization every navItem inherit wheelnav's properties. (You can find it in [documentation](http://wheelnavjs.softwaretailoring.net/documentation/core.html), press 'init' and 'create' buttons under Methods section. Info about navItems [here](http://wheelnavjs.softwaretailoring.net/documentation/navItem.html).)

Here is a sample code for your current question:

```
wheel.initWheel(["1", "2", "3", "4"]);
wheel.titleRotateAngle = 0;
wheel.navItems[0].titleRotateAngle = 180;
wheel.navItems[1].titleRotateAngle = 180;
wheel.createWheel();
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for your quick answer. However this does not work for me. yes, titleRotateAngle attribute is set to the first two navItems, however it does not effect the display of the wheel at all. I found that i can use wheel.navItems[n].navTitle.rotate(value) however it is overwritten after every action done to the wheelnav :/